# Error Message : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm aware of what the issue is stating but I am confused to how my program is making this error.

I have two arrays of strings in a dll file:

```
string[] Names = { };
string[] SignalQuality = { };
```

The code that I set again the `strings[]` inside the class:

```
Names[i] = networkName;
SignalQuality[i] = network.wlanSignalQuality + "%";
```

And when I call them from my program using Tuple:

```
string[] Names = Network.GetAvailableRouters().Item1;
string[] Signals = Network.GetAvailableRouters().Item2;
Console.WriteLine(Names[0] + " " + Signals[0]);
```

Throws me an exception message inside the class:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.'

Full Code:

```
public static Tuple<string[], string[]> GetAvailableRouters()
{
    //Declare here as I said
    string[] Names = { }; 
    string[] SignalQuality = { };
    WlanClient client = new WlanClient();

    foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlaninterface in client.Interfaces)
    {
        Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlaninterface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
        foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = network.dot11Ssid;
            string networkName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength);
            Names[i] = networkName;
            SignalQuality[i] = network.wlanSignalQuality + "%";
            i++;

        }
    }
    //return with Tuple.Create()
    return Tuple.Create(Names, SignalQuality);
}
```

Comment: How to use a breakpoint and why they are useful -
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) have fixed size length and since you didn't initialized them, and because you don't know the number of items you probably should use a generic [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. `Lists` are dynamically resizable, arrays are not:

```
List<string> Names = new List<string>();
Names.Add(networkName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code will perform poorly if you are calling `Network.GetAvailableRouters()` twice. Put that into a variable like `var availableRouters` then access `availableRouters.Item1` and `availableRouters.Item2` respectively.

Secondly you seem to require building a collection of items with an unknown length (because you are using a `foreach` not a `for`), so `string[]` is not what you want which requires a predetermined number of items in your array.

Try using a generic list of strings (i.e. `var names = new List<string>();`) and call it's add function like so `names.Add(networkName)` to build your collection.
It is essentially a string array with added features to allow you to add to a "perceived" unbounded collection.